# PHP custom types in SOAP call

Tags: php

I have to call a SOAP service with this typeof struct:

```
string CodeType

struct CallProcedure {
 CodeType Code;
}
```

I have a code like this:

```php
class CodeType
{
 public $CodeType; 
}

class CallProcedure
{
    private $Code;
    public function __construct($parameter)
    {
        $tempCode = new CodeType();
        $tempCode->CodeType= $parameter;
        $this->Code= $tempCode;
    }

    public function Code()
     {
        return this->Code;
     }
}
```

But I recieved a message from the SOAP server saying:

```
Object of class CodeType could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the type of data.
I replicated his error when using `echo` (since the result is an object, it can not be converted to string by `echo`).

Use `var_dump` instead of `echo` to verify the data of the created object, in addition you have an error you need the sign of dollar in the return of the function Code.

The call should be like this:

```
$A = new CallProcedure("Hello world");
var_dump($A->Code());
```